# assigning mouse actions forJPopupMenu

Tags: swing, jpopupmenu

I need small help from you. How can we perform action for mouse popup menu?

I created a JPopupMenu with some menu items for mouse right button in my program.

Suppose....

```
click the mouse right button -->load
                                copy
                                paste
                                cut
```

Now I want following thing: How can write the mouse events to perform the actions for every individual menu items.

If I select the "load" item it has to call another class, like that. Please help to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to assign `ActionListeners` or `Actions` to your specific menu items which then perform the specific tasks. You can find a detailed introduction to [menus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) and [actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) in the swing tutorials.